# Error while setting user and host name in mysql administrator

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to add a new remote host to give access to my database .But when i am trying to save it ,it gives error as " **cant retrieve user information** " in the command line .and then the mysql administrator closes .

The complete error coming is "**Error while storing the user information.The user might have been deleted .please refresh the userlist**"

What is possibly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give useful advices without having relevant information available. What version of MySQL Workbench are you using? In what OS? What is MySQL Server version and OS of your server? Also, can you post a screenshot of the errors? Does something relevant appear in `View -> Output` when you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with this structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_info`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
  `User` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Full_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Contact_information` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Icon` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User`),
  KEY `user_info_Full_name` (`Full_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Stores additional user information';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```